# Need to find the parent node id

Tags: xslt

This is my sample input

```
<table id="1" style="width=100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="1">
            <table id="2" style="width=50%">
                <tr>
                    <td id="2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using xslt1.0. when ever the template match 'td' is matched, i need to find the corresponding table id value..For example, If the td with id=1 is matched,i want to take style attribute value from table(id=1) and if the td with id=2 is matched,i want to take style attribute value from table(id=2). I have written `ancestor::table/@style` in my template, but both td are referring the styles of table with id=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have written
>   `ancestor::table/@style` in my
>   template

You were close. Because there can be more than one `table` in the `ancestor` axis, you need to get the first one like in `ancestor::table[1]/@style`. Of course, if you are absolute sure there is always a chain of `table` ->  `tr` ->  `td` (not optional `tbody`) then you could go with @Flack's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in 'td' context, use this XPath:

```
../../@style
```

Test XSLT against your sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../@style"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
width=100%width=50%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath it works perfectly

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table[1]/@style"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
width=100%width=50%
```